# Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to initialize a Double-Link List and creating new nodes within it
However, I keep getting this error when trying to create a new node "temp", filling it with data, then inserting it into the dLink list.
Here's the code:

```
// Node of the Double-Link List
struct node {
    double x, y;
    node *prev;
    node *next;
};
// Double-Link List Function
struct dList {
    node *head;
    node *rear;
};
// Function to check if a list is empty
bool isEmpty(dList *L)
{
    if (L == NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}
// Function to insert a node at the rear of a list
void insertAtRear(dList *L, double a, double b)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->x = a;
    temp->y = b;
    if (isEmpty(L))
    {
        L->head = temp;
        L->rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    temp->prev = L->rear;
    L->rear->next = NULL;
    L->rear = temp;
    return;
}
// Main Function
int main() {
    dList *L1=NULL;
    dList *L2=NULL;
    string fileName1, fileName2;
    cout << "Please insert the name of the first csv file in which the information is stored:" << endl;
    cin >> fileName1;
    readFile(L1, fileName1);
    cout << "Please insert the name of the second csv file in which the information is stored:" << endl;
    cin >> fileName2;
    readFile(L2, fileName2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**I didn't include the readFile function seeing as it's not the issue, just keep in mind that I'm calling insertAtRear() from within that function**

I tried setting *prev and *next as nullptr when initializing them in the structure init.
I'm aware that the issue is related to pointers and them not being correctly initialized but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the issue.

Comment: What do expect to happen when `L == NULL` (a.k.a. `isEmpty(L)`) and you do `L->head = temp`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
At first, I didn't do: dList *L1=NULL
I just did: dList *L1
Then I called a function Initialize(L1) that sets L1->head=NULL & L1->rear=NULL.

But it did not allow me to do this, it said: "Uninitialized Local Variable L1 used".

I'm guessing that when I do L == NULL, the head and rear disappear? But I couldn't compile the code without adding L = NULL

Answer (score 0):

*@Yksisarvinen* is right, did you initialize `L1` & `L2` in the `readFile` function? they appear to be null.

> *"I'm aware that the issue is related to pointers and them not being correctly initialized"*

You can initialize objects correctly with class constructors

```
struct node {
  double x, y;
  node *prev;
  node *next;
  node(const double &x, const double &y) : x(x), y(y), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
  node(const node&) = delete;
 ~node(void) {}
};

struct dList {
  node *head;
  node *rear;
  dList(node *head=nullptr, node *rear=nullptr) : head(head), rear(rear) {}
  dList(const dList&) = delete;
 ~dList(void)
  {
    for (; head != nullptr; head = rear)
    {
      rear = head->next;
      head->next = head->prev = nullptr;
      delete head;
    }
  }
};
```

implementation of `isEmpty` & `insertAtRear` should be something like:

```
bool isEmpty(dList *L)
{
  if (L == nullptr) throw "error: null dList pointer!!!!";
  return ((L.head == nullptr) || (L.rear == nullptr));
}

bool insertAtRear(dList *L, double a, double b)
{
  if (L == nullptr) return false;
  node *temp = new node(a, b);
  if (isEmpty(L)) L->head = L->rear = temp;
  else { temp->prev = L->rear; L->rear = L->rear->next = temp; }
  return true;
}
```

and `main` function can be:

```
int main() {
  dList L1;
  dList L2;
  ...
  readFile(&L1, fileName1);
  ...
  readFile(&L2, fileName2);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I hope this is helpful